# cURL send json file to API with custom header in PHP

Tags: php, curl

So having a small issue sending a file to API using `cURL`

This is the given example that works

```
curl -X POST \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d @trace.json \
  "https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v4/mapbox.driving.json"
```

This return me the accurate data.

What I am trying to achieve is the same but using vanilla PHP

```
function sendRequest() {
    // initialise the curl request
    $request = curl_init('https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v4/mapbox.driving.json');

    // send a file
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'header' => 'Content-Type:application/json',
      'file' => '@' . realpath('trace.json')
    ));

    // output the response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($request);

    // close the session
    curl_close($request);

}
sendRequest();
```

I have tried this, but this returns me a invalid input error, although the input is copied from the example.

I have a feeling that its either down to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` that I am sending or the whole structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, and not pass headers to `POST` data, like this:

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:application/json'
));

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'file_contents' => '@' . realpath('trace.json')
));
```

Comment: `{"message":"Unexpected token -"}`

Comment: @AndrejsGubars, but error in your data. Not in my code. you are waiting for someone else to do everything for you?

Comment: no, error is not in a data. if you read carefully I state that when i call the example method on a file 'trace.json' it works and there are no error, how come that if I call cURL on exactly the same file it produces me error incorrect input. CLEARLY it's down to PHP cURL call